# Composite of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Give an example of field extensions $L_{1}, L_{2}$ of $F$ for which $[L_{1}L_{1}:F]<[L_{1}:F][L_{2}:F]$.

$\bf{Solution}.$ We have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{18}:\mathbb{Q})] = 4$ (Eisenstein criterion in $x^{4}-2$ and $x^{4}-18$). Say $a = \sqrt[4]{2}, b=\sqrt[4]{18}$. We have $b$ satisfies the polynomial $x^{2} - 3\sqrt{2} = x^{2} - 3a^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})[x]$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{18}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{18})] \leq 2.$ Thus
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{18}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{18}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]\leq 8 < 16 = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{18}:\mathbb{Q})].$$

This is correct?

*$L_{1}L_{2}$ is the composition

Comment: Well, a trivial solution is to just take $L_{1} = L_{2}$, but maybe you're supposed to avoid this?

Comment: Alternatively, for a less silly example, let $\xi$ be a primitive $3$rd root of unity, and consider the extensions $L_{1} = \mathbb{Q}(\xi \sqrt[3]{2}), L_{2} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Then $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ both have degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, since the minimal polynomial of both generating elements is $X^{3}-2$, which is irreducible by Eisenstein at $2$. However, $L_{1}L_{2} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \xi)$, which you can see has degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I understood $[ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{18}) ] \leq 8 $. I know that $8 < 16$ is always true. But did you use a particular result to get $8 < 16$ in this context ?